# Why is my Chessboard variable undefined in my Express app?

Tags: javascript, express, npm, pug

In my index.js file I am trying to make another page for my chessboard, but my variable is undefined as if i never installed the package

I have done npm install --save chess.js and placed the min.js and min.css files in my public folder

this is the part of my file

```
router.get('/chess/', (req,res,next) =>{
  var board1 = Chessboard('board1', 'start');//this is the line
  res.render('color',{
    title: 'Chess Page',
    board1: board1
  });
```

this is my error 
Chessboard is not defined
ReferenceError: Chessboard is not defined
    at that location

I wanted the board to show up and for it to recognize my variable

Comment: did you import ChessBoard from somewhere did you miss the import?

Comment: do you mean the npm install --save chess.js ? do i need to write import at the top of my js files?

Comment: are you doing this on a browser or on backend ? if you are doing this on the browser add this to your head 
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chrisoakman/chessboardjs@1.0.0/dist/chessboard-1.0.0.min.js" integrity="sha384-8Vi8VHwn3vjQ9eUHUxex3JSN/NFqUg3QbPyX8kWyb93+8AC/pPWTzj+nHtbC5bxD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`